# A question about random walk in Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Would someone please explain me what does the highlighted sentence mean? I don't understand what really "even" and "odd" mean here? 
I would be appreciate if you can help me in a demonstrated picture.

[image]

Comment: "Be even" in this context actually means winding up at zero. However, it might be easier to see it as "being in any state matching up with an even number", which would also be true and would imply the desired statement. It is true because the position at an odd time index is a sum of an odd number of odd numbers (+1 and -1 are both odd), so it is odd.

Comment: It means being in an even numbered state and since the step size is 1, that is not possible after an odd number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

To see this intuitively, take some examples: Start from $0$ and try to return to it. Can you do it in $1$ step? No, you need at least $2$. Can you do it in $3$ steps? Generalize this and you will see that you need an even number of steps to return to $0$ starting from it.

---

This would be different, if the chain could remain in a state with positive probability. But here, you have to move in each step to another state.